# ADB command-line options when debugging from Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb

I am using Eclipse to debug an Android application on a device. I would like to keep the application data between debug sessions. I should be able to do this from the command line with something like this:

```
adb uninstall -k com.package.myprogram
adb install -r MyProgram.apk
```

But then, I have to debug on the command-line -- Eclipse is much nicer! Is there anyway to set these options for when I am debugging with Eclipse?? Or somehow set these options through an ADB shell, but then still use Eclipse for catching Breakpoints?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does not do any black magic! for all matters ends up accessing adb.exe to talk to the device. by just typing adb on your command line, you will get host of options with which you can do a lot of things. Apart from adb, there are other tools too which can help debug. Research a bit on which suits you best.

Comment: What I mean is that it is nice to hit the breakpoints in Eclipse. But if I am using Eclipse, then I don't seem to be able to modify the install and uninstall commands.

Can you recommend or suggest other Android debug tools? I know only of Eclipse and ADB.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a launch configuration for your Android project in Eclipse (in the *Run* menu). If you modify your application code and run the launch configuration again, Eclipse will install the new version of your application on the device without touching any of its data. There is absolutely no need to uninstall the old version first.